# Can RabbitMQ invoke directly a Web Service (REST, SOAP) on Message Dequeue?

Tags: web-services, rabbitmq, integration

Can RabbitMQ invoke directly a Web Service (REST, SOAP) on Message Dequeue ?

I mean a native direct invocation, with no external consumer that do the job.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No. RabbitMQ is a messaging routing/queueing system. If you need that, then you have to implement it with your app